# Struts 2 Page Include Access Request Object Attribute From Property Tag

Tags: java, struts2

I am including a JSP page using the s:include tag:

```
<s:include value="/WEB-INF/jsp/centers/tpa/admin/users/UserEmployerAccessRow.jsp" />
```

I have several objects that I want to make available to this include and I am trying to store them into the request before the include happens.  I am using the s:set tag to store to the request object:

```
<s:set var="employer_tmp" value="employer" scope="request" />
```

Everything in the jsp works as expected up to this point.  The included jsp is not able to access objects in the request from a s:property tag.  Here is what I have inside of the UserEmployerAccessRow.jsp:

```
<s:property value="#request[employer_tmp]" />
```

I have also tried it this way:

```
<s:property value="#employer_tmp" />
```

I have verified that the object is in the request by doing this:

```
<% out.println(request.getAttribute("employer_tmp")); %>
```

My guess is that the s:property is looking for the internal map that Struts sets up for the request and not looking at the actual request object.  Does anyone know any markup to force the s:property to grab something out of the request object?  It seems like overkill to have to run another action in the loop that I have this include in.  I cannot use s:param to hand parameters to the include because it only handles simple http parameters and not objects.  Thanks in advance for any direction you guys can provide!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the problem.  The attribute name needs to be quoted in the s:property tag:

```
<s:property value="#request['employer_tmp']" />
```

Comment: Alternatively you can use `#request.employer_tmp`, that works too